# Why can't I focus a control that I reveal with slideDown()?

Tags: jquery

I want to reveal a div with an input inside when you click a button, and set its focus.

If I use show(), it works, but if I use slideDown() **the focus is lost after the animation completes**. How can I prevent this from happening?

Sample code:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#MyButton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".SlidingDiv").slideDown();
        $("#MyInput").focus();
    });
});

<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="MyButton" />
<div class="SlidingDiv" style="display:none;"><input type="text" id="MyInput" /></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#MyButton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".SlidingDiv").slideDown(function(){
            // Callback function - will occur when sliding is complete.
            $("#MyInput").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me in 2 out of 3 instances but in the 3rd, executing $("#MyInput").focus(); makes the panel disappear or more likely repositions it out of site within another container. How I hate Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only focus the element once the DIV has fully stopped sliding?
not sure...